# Why do I see so many tombstones in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

When I do a table repair, I see a lot of warnings like the following:

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:112958] 2016-04-07 15:39:33,160 SliceQueryFilter.java:236 - Read 10002 live and 2857 tombstoned cells
```

But I do not delete anything and do not set TTLs, so nothing has been deleted.  Why are there so many tombstones? The datasize is about 200G, but I have inserted some cells with NULL.

Comment: get  it at http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.0/java-driver/reference/unsettingValues.html?scroll=unsetting-values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the [same issue](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cassandra-user/201603.mbox/%3C16E7E98A-F16E-43CD-9523-159A5601C4B5@gmail.com%3E) recently. And the reason was that I was inserting NULL values. I just did not know that I did.

If you use a prepared statement and you do not set some of the parameters, or you set them to NULL, or if you insert a JSON object that does not contain a key for every column of the table, then you end up with a tombstone for each of those columns.

In case of the prepared statement you can avoid the tombstone by explicitly setting unused parameters as [unset](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.0/java-driver/reference/unsettingValues.html?scroll=unsetting-values). See [CASSANDRA-7304](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7304).

Unfortunately there is no such syntax/API for JSON inserts yet. Have a look at [CASSANDRA-11424](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11424) to check the progress.